# infiniteScroll not working on nz-modal body how can I make it work

Tags: angular

I have an modal view to show and a list of contents in it, so want to make it scroll and to show more content. I use ng-zorro and /ngx-infinite-scroll

here is the code but it not working how can I make it work

```
   <nz-modal nzWidth="80%" nzWrapClassName="vertical-center-modal" [(nzVisible)]="isVisible"
              nzTitle="参数信息" (nzOnCancel)="onCancel()" (nzOnOk)="onOk()"
              class="demo-infinite-container"
              infiniteScroll
              [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
              [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50"
              (scrolled)="onScroll()"
              [scrollWindow]="false"
              [nzBodyStyle]="{height: '300px'}"
    >

        <nz-list [nzDataSource]="data" [nzRenderItem]="item">
          <ng-template #item let-item>
            <nz-list-item>
              <nz-list-item-meta
                [nzTitle]="nzTitle"
                nzAvatar="https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/ODTLcjxAfvqbxHnVXCYX.png"
                [nzDescription]="item.email">
                <ng-template #nzTitle>
                  <a href="https://ng.ant.design">{{item.name.last}}</a>
                </ng-template>
              </nz-list-item-meta>
            </nz-list-item>
          </ng-template>
          <nz-spin *ngIf="loading && hasMore" class="demo-loading"></nz-spin>
        </nz-list>
    </nz-modal>
```